# Values passing NULL in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I want to upload data from a table (from my base) in a DropDownList.

The table is 'Poste'and it has a model 'Poste'.

The view showing the DropDownList is 'Gestion' and this its code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", new SelectList(Model.PostesItems, "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste"))%></div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédente :")%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivante :")%></div>

        </fieldset>
         <% } %>
```

As you see, it is import from a FlowViewModel, which the code is :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class FlowViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        public List<Poste> PostesItems { get; set; }
        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the controller which returns the view :

```
public class ProfileGaController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
        {

            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList();
               viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
               viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();
               return View(viewModel);



        }
```

The problem that an Exception appears in the execution which mentionne that the values are passing NULL :
[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a constructor for `FlowViewModel` and intitialise `PostesItems = new List<Poste>()`, so that if there aren't any items it will be an empty list rather than null.

Edit, in case it's not clear, try change `FlowViewModel` to this -

```
    public class FlowViewModel
    {
        public FlowViewModel()
        {
            PostesItems = new List<Poste>()
        }

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        public List<Poste> PostesItems { get; set; }
        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit again: Solved this in chat. The Index action was calling an Index view that worked fine, but then *that* view was trying to load a *different* view using Javascript, and not passing in a model, so it's Model that's null in the screenshot.

Comment: the same problem persist :(((

Comment: @anouar. The constructor won't help - the property gets overwritten by the action anyway in the line `viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList();`

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say, try change `viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList();` to `viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes == null ?? new List<Poste>() : db.Postes.ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly for me. What happens if you change

```
viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList();
```

to

```
viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList() ?? new List<Poste>();
```

And (possibly do the same for the other two properties as well)?

(I'm surprised you have to do this. I thought `ToList` returned an empty list rather than null.)

Comment: I try but nothing as result,,,the exception still appear

Comment: @anouar. In that case, the null is probably not `PostesItems`, it must be something else. Can you double check that by putting a breakpoint on `return View(viewModel);` in your action and looking at the contents of the `PostesItems` property?

Comment: @anouar. Actually, looking again, can you please post your `PostesItems` class in your question, maybe one of the properties of one of the items is `null`, or one of your items in the list is `null` and that is causing your error.

Comment: ,,,the value is FlowViewModel

Comment: ,,,I don't have a PostesItems class ,,,it's just a list in the view model : FlowViewModel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29854/discussion-between-anouar-and-andy-brown)

Answer (score 1):

What you really need here is a property with a backing field.

```
 public class FlowViewModel
 {
    private List<Poste> _postesItems = null;
    public List<Poste> PostesItems
    {
       get
       {
          return _postesItems ?? new List<Poste>();
       }
       set
       {
          _postesItems = value ?? new List<Poste>();
       }
    }
 }
```

This solves all your problems and you don't need the viewModel lines anymore...